# How may I remove \EndIf and \EndFor in algorithmicx?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode

For space consideration, I wish to condense my pseudocode.

I find it a bit annoying to me to always have a \EndIf or \EndFor at the end of every block, especially when inside the block only lies one statement. e.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{INPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{OUTPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{A}{}
    \ForAll{$a\in A$}
        \If{$a\geq b$}
            \State\Return $a$
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

To save the space, I wish to remove them, although it may be non-standard.

Once I do it, the code cannot be compiled due to errors.

**Is there any "illegal" trick to kinda remove them from the output PDF?**

Comment: Do you want to remove them from the tex file and/or from the output?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @AndrewSwann  Output. Question updated.

Comment: @Jubobs  Thanks for the advice. Corrected as suggested.

Comment: Doesn't loading the `algpseudocode` package with the `noend` option do the trick?

Comment: @Jubobs  You mean removing `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` and doing `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Don't remove the End parts, it is rather an important thing for understanding algorithms, especially for non-programmers.

Comment: @Jubobs  Wow, it works like a charm. Mind posting it as answer so that I accept it to benefit the possible future learners?

Comment: @daleif Those endings take up nearly half of the space. Conference paper has a page limit on the papers.

Comment: Then rewrite, change the font size on the algorithm. You have to remember that others have to read and understand your text.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Preventing *end* keywords from being typeset

Simply pass the `noend` option to the `algpseudocode` package: substitute `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}` for `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` in your code and you get

[image]

### To avoid having to use `\EndIf` and `\Endfor` in your input file

(After clarification by the OP, this turns out to be off-topic.)

Missing `\EndIf` and `\EndFor` will generate errors; you cannot simply omit them in your input file. If you want to save yourself the hassle of having to use those macros in your input file in order to close control-flow statements, you can always define a macro that combines `\If` and `\EndIf`, another that combines `\ForAll` and `\EndFor`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand*{\Let}[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#2\strut}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{INPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{OUTPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\sForAll[2]{ \ForAll{#1}#2\EndFor} % snappy version of \ForAll...\EndFor
\newcommand\sIf[2]{ \If{#1}#2\EndIf}          % snappy version of \If...\EndIf

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{A}{}
    \sForAll{$a\in A$}{
        \sIf{$a\geq b$}{
            \State\Return $a$
        }
    }
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}`